# How to install php5-auth-pam on newer versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, php

I'm trying to install php5-auth-pam on Ubuntu 14.04, but package doesn't exist after Ubuntu 12.04.

I've tried by downloading package here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-auth-pam

I've done things like:

```
dpkg -I php*.deb
apt-get install -f
```

I can't match dependencies, and I don't know how to install them too.

Comment: `apt-get -uf install php5-auth-pam`  didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes thats right,check this :

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-auth-pam/+bug/798571

if doesnt exist yet, it is maybe removed from repository...
and also check this :

> http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/web/php5-auth-pam

i think there's not newer version for this package.goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an older package and just hope *it works*. There has been several interactions of each of the dependencies (libpam, php) which won't just install the package. The virtual package phpapi-20090626 don't exist in newer versions, hence the dependency won't be resolved. Also, the software itself was abandoned by upstream, so you won't find a version that would "just work". Try another alternatives instead of this library.

Comment: Fact is there is no known alternative. That's why i asked !
Thanks for your long answer, I know something more today.